# Does Array.find method return a copy or a reference of the matched element from a given array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

What does the `Array.find` method return; a specific copy of a found value or the reference of a found value?

Comment: You mean `array.find`?

Comment: yes and i corrected by post.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "copy"? And why are you wondering this specifically for `.find()`? Your question looks  a duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language), but I'm not fully convinced.

Comment: new instance which does not related to the array which it belongs. Pass by value mainly

Comment: @MDJahidHasan JavaScript is pass-by-value, so you will _always_ get a value. But that value could be a reference to an object. But that is completely unrelated to the `Array.prototype.find()` function. That's just how JavaScript works. See the link I put in my previous comment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (emphasis theirs):

> The find() method returns the **value** of the **first element** in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Whether it returns a copy of or a reference to the value will follow normal JavaScript behaviour, i.e. it'll be a copy if it's a primitive, or a reference if it's a complex type.

```js
let foo = ['a', {bar: 1}];
let a = foo.find(val => val === 'a');
a = 'b';
console.log(foo[0]); //still "a"
let obj = foo.find(val => val.bar);
obj.bar = 2;
console.log(foo[1].bar); //2 - reference
```

Answer (score 5):

That's a tricky question.

Technically speaking, `find` always returns a value, but that value could be a reference if the item you're looking for is an object. It will still be a value nonetheless.

It's similar to what's happening here:

```
let a = { some: "object" };

let b = a;
```

You are copying the **value** of the variable `a` into `b`. It just so happens that the value is a **reference** to the object `{ some: "object" }`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

```js
const obj = {}

console.log(obj.find)

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']

console.log(arr.find(e => e === 'a'))
console.log(arr.find(e => e ==='c'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns Value

The find() method returns the value of the first element in an array that pass a test (provided as a function).

The find() method executes the function once for each element present in the array:

If it finds an array element where the function returns a true value, find() returns the value of that array element (and does not check the remaining values)
Otherwise, it returns undefined

[Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_find2)